# Magento 2.3 - Product filter with multi select custom attribute

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I trying to do filter the product collection with my custom attribute(`Type` : `Multi select`).

It is not working.

Kindly help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try to use **addAttributeToFilter** with or condition

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code',
    array(
        array('finset'=> array('237')),
        array('finset'=> array('238')),
        array('finset'=> array('239')),
    )
);
```

Comment: kindly update code for AND condition also

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :-**

```
$collection = $this->productFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1));
```

Comment: this is for dropdown